Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin

The class is loaded from D:/Gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.3-all/6en3ugtfdg5xnpx44z4qbwgas/gradle-8.3/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/collections/CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.class e: D:\ReactNative\project_name\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\utils\TaskUtils.kt: (25, 7): Class 'kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt__CollectionsKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

Error occurs when I tried to sync the project.
The below-mentioned are all versions that I used.

android/build.gradle

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 27
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists


package.json

"dependencies": {
    react:"18.2.0"
    react-native:"0.73.0"
}

I'm trying to update the sdk version 33 to 34. How can I resolve this issue???...

Your error message states that you are using the wrong version of Kotlin - 1.9.0 when it should be 1.6.0. So in your code, change the following
kotlin_version = '1.9.0'

to
kotlin_version = '1.6.0'


Kotline 1.6.0 not fully compatible with AGP and latest Android SDK tools. @Thomasino73
